# How to implement python auto-mailer using smtplib?

Tags: python, smtp, email

I'm trying to write a python `auto-mailer` using `smtplib`. I've got it running but i keep hitting my except statement.

code looks like this.

```
    sender = ['..........@gmail.com']
    receivers = ['.......@gmail.com']

    subject = "does this work?"
    message = "this is a cool email"

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
        print("Successfully sent email")
        server.quit()
    except smtplib.SMTPException:
        print("Error: unable to send email")
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: stack trace as follows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/......py", line 38, in <module>
    email_protocol()
  File "C:/Users/....py", line 33, in email_protocol
    server.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\smtplib.py", line 867, in sendmail
    raise SMTPSenderRefused(code, resp, from_addr)
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError c33sm2599297qtb.76 - gsmtp', ['....@gmail.com'])

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: post the stack trace without exception handling

Comment: edited and reposted

Comment: There is a rather clear error message, which includes a link to a page with more information, what specifically is the issue?

Comment: i am a fool in man's shoes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty self explanatory. You require to provide authentication.

```
server.login('<gmaiL-id>', '<password>')
```

Put this after `server.starttls()`

Refer https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.login for further details